# Options for user self service of membership

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions

We are pretty new to paid memberships and I find I don't know how to answer basic use cases.

We have a membership with 3 levels (bronze, silver, gold).  The membership is associated with a monthly recurring contribution. The user sets the contribution amount which is done via a price set where the amount is $1 and they can set the quantity.

This is all done via stock CiviCRM; not webform.  We do not give users access to the CiviCRM dashboard.  We do use Drupal Views if that helps.

Users are asking me:

1. How can I change my membership type?  (e.g. Silver to Gold)
2. How can I change my contribution amount?
3. How can I end my membership and contributions?

Is there a page I can send them to where they can change these things?

I apologize if this is super basic.  I've done a bunch of searches on here and can't find an answer.

Thank you!

CiviCRM 5.37.2 on Drupal 7.X.

Edit to add: We are using Stripe as a payment processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your membership type, you just need to renew your membership at a new level.  Assuming the memberships are both tied to the same organization (check your membership type settings, but this is almost always the case), the renewal will be considered a [membership upsell](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-7297).

The answer for questions 2 and 3 are similar, and are related to your payment processor, which you haven't mentioned.

Most (but not all) processors support what you're requesting.  If they do, then the contribution receipt will have the following at the bottom:

```
This membership will be renewed automatically. You can cancel the
auto-renewal option by visiting this web page
https://example.org/civicrm/contribute/unsubscribe?reset=1&mid=12353&cs=6eda08dad7164135b0ac8b112ce6c128_1592902428_inf.

You can update billing details for this automatically renewed membership
by visiting this web page
https://example.org/civicrm/contribute/updatebilling?reset=1&mid=12353&cs=6eda08dad7164135b0ac8b112ce6c128_1592902428_inf.
```

Keep in mind that these links are only good for a limited period of time (7 days by default but can be changed under **Administer menu » System Settings » Misc**). Also, depending on your configuration, users may not be receiving a receipt for every recurring setting.  If not, you may need to change that in the database - look for the `is_email_receipt` field in the `civicrm_contribution_recur` table, which defaults to `1` (true) but may have been changed based on your settings.

Note that changing the period the links are good for only affects future links, not links that have already been emailed.

Comment: Jon, thank you so much!!  Quick follow up questions:  
1. Is it correct that if I click to update my billing details then I can also change the amount?  
2. If I change the time period for the link to 30 days, then the user should always be able to change their amount, right?
3. Is there a way to offer those links in a View or a Drupal page somehow?  I'm not sure how to generate "mid" and "cs" values.

Thank you!!

Comment: For 1) it's processor-dependent - e.g. PayPal allows it, but last I checked you could only change the amount by 20% every 180 days. 2) 31 days should work, assuming no one tries to use a link other than the most recent one. 3) `mid` is the membership ID.  `cs` is the checksum. AFAIK there's no way to generate those in Views. I wrote an [extension that puts a button with checksum on the Civi user-facing dashboard](https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-self-service-user-dashboard) (but for events, not contributions). It would work if the user was logged in. It may also work with Form Builder.